# Hide information in window.screen

Tags: javascript, firefox, window, screen, user-tracking

Is it possible to instruct Firefox to hide the information contained in `window.screen`?

According to this paper [1], it can be used for tracking purposes.

Thank you.

[1] https://panopticlick.eff.org/browser-uniqueness.pdf

Comment: I'd be more worried about the user agent string. There's not a lot you can do with a screen resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, it's not possible.  for example:

```
 screen.width=999;
 alert(screen.width); // shows: 1920
```